# Plot complex inequality in Julia

Tags: julia, implicit, complex-numbers

I have the mathematical expression `|z - (-1)| < 1`, with `z` element of Complexes, which is equivalent of a circle of radius 1 centered in `(x,y)=(-1,0)`.

1. How can I plot this expression,
2. preserving the structure of the mathematical expression it was derived from, as much as
   possible?
3. It should be an area.

**What I tried so far:**

```
using ImplicitEquations, Plots

f(a,b) = abs.(a+im*b - (-1))
plot(f<1)
```

The error I got:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching isless(::typeof(f), ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  isless(::Union{StatsBase.PValue, StatsBase.TestStat}, ::Real) at /home/buddhilw/.julia/packages/StatsBase/PGTj8/src/statmodels.jl:514
  isless(::AbstractGray{T} where T, ::Real) at /home/buddhilw/.julia/packages/ColorTypes/6m8P7/src/operations.jl:31
  isless(::ForwardDiff.Dual{Tx, V, N} where {V, N}, ::Integer) where
Tx at /home/buddhilw/.julia/packages/ForwardDiff/UDrkY/src/dual.jl:144
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] <(x::Function, y::Int64)
   @ Base ./operators.jl:279
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[62]:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot of [documentation](https://nbviewer.org/github/jverzani/ImplicitEquations.jl/blob/master/docs/examples.ipynb) for ImplicitEquations, but something stands out: you're not using the right operators. The package relies on unusual operators to represent math expressions with Julia functions: ≪ (\ll[tab]), ≦ (\leqq[tab]), ⩵ (\Equal[tab]), ≶ (\lessgtr[tab]) or ≷ (\gtrless[tab]), ≧ (\geqq[tab]), ≫ (\leqq[tab]).

So that fix would look like:

```
using ImplicitEquations, Plots

f(a,b) = sqrt((a+1)^2 + b^2)
plot(f ≪ 1)
```

Update:

`f(a,b) = abs(a + im*b - (-1))` causes a method ambiguity error. `f(a, b) = hypot(a+1, b)`, which is what `abs` calls, also causes the error. It looks like the issue is that at some point in `hypot`, `OInterval(x::Ointerval)` is called, but dispatch could not pick between `(::Type{T})(x::T) where T<:Number` in `boot.jl` or `OInterval(a)` in `intervals.jl`. Just redefining `OInterval(a::Ointerval) = a` won't work either because you run into another `MethodError` for `decompose(::OInterval)`, which is a method intended for processing floats. Looking at [the comments in `intervals.jl`](https://github.com/jverzani/ImplicitEquations.jl/blob/c9dae8684bbc8c86926f889ed22755bfc9abcabb/src/intervals.jl#L52), the dispatch seems like a work in progress.

Comment: are you sure that this works when `f` yields a `Complex` number? I tried your code and got `ImplicitEquations.OInterval(::ImplicitEquations.OInterval) is ambiguous`

Comment: This [PR](https://github.com/jverzani/ImplicitEquations.jl/pull/38) will fix this example. (There was a method ambiguity, and `hypot` needed defining. There is more work to be done to gracefully handle complex numbers.